# Unity launcher question - Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, appearance

I want to make the launcher flat. Does anyone know how to disable the "shadow' at the top?

First question I've ever posted on askubunut, sorry if it's inappropriate or if I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: You can probably do this by changing the theme [Numix](http://gamblisfx.com/how-to-install-numix-theme-and-icons-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/) comes to mind - alternately make the background color the same you you don't notice...). It may be hardcoded in as many parts of Unity sadly are. (BTW, the question is fine but it may help to add more detail (screenshot etc :)

Comment: Hi Wilf, thanks or the reply (and sorry for the delay getting back to you). I did try changing the theme but that's a little "all or nothing". I would prefer to leave everything the way it is by default except get rid of that little shadow. Maybe I'll look into how themes work and see if I can find some kind of work around.